# Salesforce Process Builder, Run a process if a field criteria is met

Tags: process-builder, automation

I'm trying to build a process that will automatically clone the Opportunity A if a "Contract Status" field equals to "Current". The thing is, that "Contract Status" field contains a formula that changes the status depending on the dates (without any manual editing).

As i understand, in Process Builder the process can only be triggered if the record is created or manually edited.

Is there a solution for triggering the process based on the field value changes?

Comment: Are those dates fields on the same object? If so, then changing the dates would cause an edit of your record, so process builder should work.

Comment: Hi Robin. Yes, those dates are on the same object, which is Opportunity. Surprisingly enough, it doesn't work though. The settings i have at the moment are the following. **Object:** Opportunity; **Criteria**: Opportunity.Contract_Status__c Equals String Current, Opportunity.StageName Equals PickList Closed Won; **Immediate Action:** Clone. But when the contract start date is reached and Contract Status is automatically changed to "Current", the opportunity is not cloned. When i open that opportunity and manually change any field and save it, only then the opportunity is cloned (manual edit)

Comment: + that's the thing, the dates are set long before the process to be triggered. So say today i create an opportunity with a "Contract Start Date" on 01/03/2016. Becuase the date is in future, the "Contract Type" (formula filed) will be "Future". But once that date is reached, "Contract Type" will automatically change to "Current". The question is, whether that automatic formula-based change is considered as "object is edited" or not.

Comment: That's not a field change man. A formula is a calculation run at query/view time. The record itself isn't changing, thus why it's never firing.

Comment: HI cricketlang. Yeah, i kinda figured out that that might be the problem =/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution would be for you to create a Process Builder that is scheduled to fire when the date is passed.  This would require the least amount of change on your side... simply switch everything you have in your immediate action to the scheduled action and you're set!

Comment: Hi David. The thing is, I dont have any "Scheduled" box, only the "Immediate Action" box. Is there a way to make it available?

Comment: That happens when you don't schedule the action first typically... so create a new set of criteria and actions :/  --- another reason I like to use Flow :), more re-usable than PB.

Comment: See [this answer](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/65734/how-to-add-time-dependent-actions-in-lightning-process-builder) to know when scheduled actions are available.

Comment: Hi David, Robin. Thank you guys for your answers! Will try to set up Process Builder as advised an see what happens, Checked out the Flow as well - that's the whole new story, maybe will get to it someday ;)